# Tweek spacy spans

Tags: python, spacy

I am using spacy un some nlp project.

I have texts in which text like this appear:

```
 text='The car comprises 4 brakes 4.1, 4.2, 4.3 and 4.4 in fig. 5, all include an ESP system. This is shown in Fig. 6. Fig. 5 shows how the motors 56 and 57 are blocked. Besides the doors (44, 45) are painted blue.'
```

I would like to treat "4.1, 4.2, 4.3 and 4.4" as one entity. In order to extract the precedent noun phrase.

Often times spacy divides that chunck into different tokens.

Assuming I have regular expressions for these spans.

What is the way to go to define an span?

code so far:

```
nlp = spacy.load('/home/jovyan/shared/public/spacy/en_core_web_sm-3.2.0')

text='The car comprises 4 brakes 4.1, 4.2, 4.3 and 4.4 in fig. 5, all include an ESP system. This is shown in Fig. 6. Fig. 5 shows how the motors 56 and 57 are blocked. Besides the doors (44, 45) are painted blue.'

doc = nlp(text)
print([token.text for token in doc])
```

how I define spans based on regex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a [chapter](https://spacy.io/usage/rule-based-matching) in Spacy doc dedicated to matching based on rules. You can use Spacy to match spans based on "regex like" rules and also you can extend the pipeline to include your rules and for example recognize entities with names using your rules.

From docs:

> Compared to using regular expressions on raw text, spaCy’s rule-based matcher engines and components not only let you find the words and phrases you’re looking for – they also give you access to the tokens within the document and their relationships. This means you can easily access and analyze the surrounding tokens, merge spans into single tokens or add entries to the named entities in doc.ents

As you can see in the following example taken from the documentation, it is very easy to define the rules using spacy's [Matcher](https://spacy.io/api/matcher) class and iterate over the results.

```
import spacy
from spacy.matcher import Matcher

nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
matcher = Matcher(nlp.vocab)
# Add match ID "HelloWorld" with no callback and one pattern
pattern = [{"LOWER": "hello"}, {"IS_PUNCT": True}, {"LOWER": "world"}]
matcher.add("HelloWorld", [pattern])

doc = nlp("Hello, world! Hello world!")
matches = matcher(doc)
for match_id, start, end in matches:
    string_id = nlp.vocab.strings[match_id]  # Get string representation
    span = doc[start:end]  # The matched span
    print(match_id, string_id, start, end, span.text)
```

On the other hand, you can also use the [EntityRuler](https://spacy.io/api/entityruler) class if you want to extend the spacy pipeline and recognize named entities based on regular expression-like rules.

I modify your code to show you more or less how it would be. Surely you have to work the rules a bit to recognize exactly the numbers with the format that interests you.

As you can see now, instead of iterating over the text tokens, I iterate over the list of entities recognized by the pipeline and keep only those that have the name `2_DIGIT`, which is the one that interests me.

```py
import spacy
from spacy.matcher import Matcher

nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_lg')
text='The car comprises 4 brakes 4.1, 4.2, 4.3 and 4.4 in fig. 5, all include an ESP system. This is shown in Fig. 6. Fig. 5 shows how the motors 56 and 57 are blocked. Besides the doors (44, 45) are painted blue.'

# Add EntityRuler to pipeline
ruler = nlp.add_pipe("entity_ruler", before="ner", config={"validate": True})
patterns = [{"label": "2_DIGIT", "pattern": [{"IS_DIGIT": True}, {"IS_PUNCT": True}, {"IS_DIGIT": True}]}]
ruler.add_patterns(patterns)

# Print 2-Digit Ents
print([(ent.label_, text[ent.start_char:ent.end_char]) for ent in doc.ents if ent.label_ == "2_DIGIT"])
```

I'm sorry I can't give you 100% working code that does what you want, but I think this is a good starting point to get what you're looking for.